# Camera not staying in new position after being put there by button in Unity

Tags: c#, loops, unity-game-engine, camera

```
public Camera MainCamera;
public GameObject TargetPosition;
public int speed = 2;
bool camera_move_enabled;

void Update()
{

    if (camera_move_enabled)
    {
        MainCamera.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, TargetPosition.transform.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        MainCamera.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, TargetPosition.transform.rotation, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

}

public void UserClickedCameraResetButton()
{
    TargetPosition.transform.position = new Vector3(-106.2617f, 68.81419f, 14.92558f);
    TargetPosition.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(39.7415f, 145.0724f, 0);
    camera_move_enabled = true;
}
```

Now whenever I click the button to move my camera to it's new position, three things happen.

1. I have to hold the button to get the camera to it's desired
   position
2. The camera jumps back after the button is deselected, un-clicked. One of these things.

And the strangest of them all.

3. All subsequent mouse clicks trigger the script.

I'm trying to figure this stuff out, I have no idea with this one. I thought I did good.

Comment: It does not appear you have included the code that triggers `UserClickedCameraResetButton()`. Could you provide additional implementation details regarding how clicking results in the method being called? Otherwise, it's tough to diagnose the latter half of your question.

Comment: It's attached to a button within unity, so it'll be triggered upon clicking the button. It's part of the interface within  unity.

Comment: I see. Do the fields of `TargetPosition.transform` ever get changed/set anywhere else? When you say the camera jumps back, do you mean to its exact original position/rotation?